# Split a string after the nth occurence of a char and before the nth+n occurence of a char in Typescript

Tags: string, typescript, split, substring

so I am trying to highlight parts of my Navbar depending on the current value of `window.location.href`.

An example string could look like this: `https://portal.ab.stringsplit.io/Example`

In my Navbar I have an Icon for **Example** which I want to highlight anytime the value of `window.location.href` equals/contains **Example**.

So I thought a good idea would be to just extract the interesting bit from the URL, in this case Example and do a simple if-statement to check if the Icon should be highlighted or not.

So far I tried to just take substring from the URL after X characters:

`https://portal.ab.stringsplit.io/` = 33 characters =>

`url =  window.location.href.substring(33))`

but I want this to be more future-proof since the URL might change AND I want this to work for any substring after the base URL, or something like:

`https://portal.ab.stringsplit.io/Example/example1/article3`

So I need something like: 'substring after '.io/' until next '/'.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What can the possible substrings be?

Comment: The substrings are simple menu labels like 'Settings, Dashboard, Profile, etc'

Comment: Do you mean like `console.log(window.location.pathname.match(/^\/([^\/]+)\//)[1]);`

Comment: Or split on a forward slash `console.log(window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean)[0]);`

Comment: Sorry, I cant get either to work. The first one says 'Object is possibly null' and the second one is undefined.

Comment: If that does not work, but you have to url, you could parse it instead `let str = "https://portal.ab.stringsplit.io/Example/example1/article3";
    let url = new URL(str);
    console.log(url.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean)[0]);` That will give `Example`